# Mock a Method with complex type

Tags: java, mockito

While mocking a method, which have complex type, returning `null` in java

```
public void sendRequest(OnlineRequest request) {
        OnlineResponse response = client.handleRequest(request);
        System.out.println( response);
}
```

```
Mockito.when(client.handleRequest(request)).thenReturn(new OnlineResponse());
```

Comment: In you example `sendRequest` method does not return anything. So it's only responsibility is to call `handleRequest` on client with argument passed to this method. It would be better to mock the `client` and then verify that `handleRequest` method was called, if of course it is the `sendRequest` method that you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your issue is that `System.out.println(response);` prints `null`?

This is most likely due to the fact that `client.handleRequest()` is not being called with the `request` you expect. This may be an error somewhere in code you haven't provided us, OR it may simply be due to the fact that `OnlineRequest` does not have an implementation of equals/hash-code, so `when()` is never triggered because it is not called with the exact same instance of `OnlineRequest` as you use in your unit tests.

You might wish to test that `handleRequest` is called with exactly the object you expect. This can be accomplished using `verify()`:

```
verify(client).handleRequest(request);
```

in your unit test. This too is dependent on the equals/hash-code implementation to determine whether `request` is the expected parameter or not.